# setItemChecked is highlighting wrong items

Tags: android, listview

hi guys i want to use a multiple list view but things are not happening as expected

i am using

the mode i am using is :`sngList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);`
and on each long click i am using :`sngList.setItemChecked(position, true);`

I am using a custom base adapter 
and i am using view re-usability
and inside the getview method i am using

```
  if(list.isItemChecked(position)){
           v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#554399"));
        }
```

but many more than the expected items are being highlighted ,is it because of view re usability ? if yes then please note that i also tried using a separate list for each item to keep its state stored in it but that didn't help either,may be i was doing something wrong ,please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When these views are reused, they will have the background color pre-applied.

You just need to unset the custom background color when the condition is false, i.e.

```
if (list.isItemChecked(position))
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#554399"));
else
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // or the original color
```

Comment: how ?i should put it in the else part ?please elaborate

Comment: never knew it was that easy lol,thanx ..i can only accept it after 11 minutes

Comment: ..i have a question for you please reply

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava Yes, what is it?

Comment: i can't unhighlight the first item